# How to get workdir and more of a completed job in slurm?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

Using scontrol makes it very easy to get the `WorkDir`, `StdErr`, `StdOut` and `Command` of a running and queued job. Is it possible to access these informations after a job is completed? I could not find any hints when looking in the documentation of sacct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sacct` will not report that information. If your cluster has the elasticsearch plugin configured, that information will be stored in elasticsearch as well as the full script submitted

The `jobcomp/filetxt` `JobCompType` plugin will also store the `WorkDir` but not the other fields.

You can also use a `SlurmctldEpilog` to store all the data you want in a file.